# To authenticate using a fingerprint device at log-in screen in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I have a non-usb finger print reader based on UART and I am trying to interface it to my computer.

Basically when the system is booted and is running I can send serial data to my finger print reader and get a reply typically an authentication of a finger print back. I have the device specification and I am communicating with the device by using termios and my problem is I want to do this in the login-screen.

So, my Idea is to run a custom program while the system is at login screen to communicate with my device and get the authentication back. The device stores the fingerprint templates on board and just sends an authentication packet back.

Any suggestions to make this happen at login screen would benefit me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Install Following packages and through **Fprintd** settings, you can Select it for login authentication ( These packages contains necessary drivers for fingerprint reader devices)

```
sudo apt-get install fprintd fprint-demo libfprint0
```

Comment: Thanks, But I do not want to use fprintf library because my device is not USB based device and my aim is to run a program at startup which will communicate with my device serially and gets back the authentication and upon reception of the same would log me into the system.